# new tab does n't work in same directiry in zsh, MacOS mojave 10.14.6

Tags: terminal, zsh

New tab isn't opened in same directory even though I configure it same profile, same directory in Prefernce. I use default terminal.app and default zsh(/bin/zsh).
why doen't this work?

Comment: You should ask this at [superuser](https://superuser.com/). I don't have my Mac at hand right now, but AFIK, you can set the working directory for the new zsh process in the preferences of terminal.app; but then your zsh takes over, and depending on whether it is started as interactive login shell, or 'only'  as interactive non-login shell, the usual zsh startup files are invoked, and they can change the working directory too; so all this information is necessay to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal.app Preferences > General you can set which directories open for new windows and new tabs, either default working directory (usually home folder) or same working directory (the directory you are currently in)

I'd recommend checking out iTerm2. It's vastly superior to Terminal.

Comment: I configured it inTerminal.app but it didn't solve this :(.. but thank you for replying.